# ZF2 redirect with POST

Tags: zend-framework2

Before user tries an unauthorized action I save:

1) Controller Name

2) Action

3) POST params

Then when user has a successful login I redirect it to...

```
$params["controller"] = "manage";
$params["action"] = $lastRequest["action"];
$params["name"] = "Ignacio";
$params["email"] = "ignacio@gmail.com";

return $this->redirect()->toRoute("user-create", $params);
```

It does redirect, but NO posted params.

How can I emulate POST request on ZF2 from a controller?
The point is I do not know where the user it is going to be redirected, so it could be GET or POST and any controller.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question correctly , so bare with me : `$params` is used in the `user-create` route , it will take what ever this route needs and discard the reset  ,I guess you must use Zend\Http\Client to make a post request to what ever url you need

Comment: With Zend\Http\Client I do a request from the server. What I want it is to redirect browser client to a URL with the POST params he did.

Comment: check out forward plugin : http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#the-forward-plugin

Comment: That plugin does not POST params, just redirect.

Answer (score 5):

This is the way I save a request and use it later to redirect to the correct action.

**1) Unauthorized action saves the request with all GET/POST params.**

```
$session = new Container('base');
$session->offsetSet("lastRequest", $event->getRequest());
```

**2) After success login, redirect to requested**

```
$session = new Container('base');
if($lastRequest = $session->offsetGet("lastRequest")) {
    //Just redirect, because I could NOT find a way to POST params
    return $this->redirect()->toUrl($lastRequest->getRequestUri());
}
```

**3) Before controller action, retrieve all POST/GET params**

```
class Module {
//...
    public function init($moduleManager)
    {
        $sharedEvents = $moduleManager->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
        $sharedEvents->attach(__NAMESPACE__, \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'preDispatch'), 100);
    }

    public function preDispatch($event)
    {

    //Unauthorized request after success login
    $session = new Container('base');
    if($lastRequest = $session->offsetGet("lastRequest")) {
        $event->getTarget()->getRequest()->setMethod($lastRequest->getMethod());
        $event->getTarget()->getRequest()->setPost($lastRequest->getPost());
        $event->getTarget()->getRequest()->setQuery($lastRequest->getQuery());

        //Delete request
        $session->offsetSet("lastRequest", null);               
    }
}
```

**4) Just use the request on any destination action as normal**

```
class ManageController extends AbstractActionController {

    public function createAction() {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost()->toArray();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't redirect user with POST data, but ZF2 provide functionality to simulate this:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#the-post-redirect-get-plugin

Comment: Hi kierzniak, thanks for your reply, but this is not what I was looking for, still not posting the params. I found a way to do it, I will post it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This solution might help but instead of using redirect, it forwards to another controller.

Before forwarding it to the other controller, replace (or update) the post params on the current request.  The receiving controller then will see the replaced (or updated) post params.

```
// Controller that handles unauthorized access

class YourController extends AbstractActionController
{

    // ...

    $request   = $this->getEvent()->getRequest();
    $postParam = new \Zend\Stdlib\Parameters();

    $postParam->set('controller', 'manage');
    $postParam->set('action',     $lastRequest['action']);
    $postParam->set('name',       'your-name';
    $postParam->set('email',      'your-email';

    $request->setPost($postParam);

    return $this->forward()->dispatch('Your\Other\UserCreateController', [
        'action' => 'userCreate',
    ]);

    // ...

}
```